# How to consume return from a union type in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

From the [link-preview-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-preview-js) library, we have a function `getLinkPreview` which has a typedefinition:

```js
export declare function getLinkPreview(text: string, options?: ILinkPreviewOptions): Promise<{
    url: string;
    mediaType: string;
    contentType: string;
    favicons: any[];
} | {
    url: string;
    title: any;
    siteName: any;
    description: any;
    mediaType: any;
    contentType: string;
    images: string[];
    videos: {
        url: any;
        secureUrl: any;
        type: any;
        width: any;
        height: any;
    }[];
    favicons: any[];
}>;
```

When I try to consume it in my application with something like this:

```
const {images} = await getLinkPreview(payload.link);
```

It throws an error both on the IDE and the console:

```
Property 'images' does not exist on type '{ url: string; mediaType: string; contentType: string; favicons: any[]; } | { url: string; title: any; siteName: any; description: any; mediaType: any; contentType: string; images: string[]; videos: { url: any; secureUrl: any; type: any; width: any; height: any; }[]; favicons: any[]; }'.ts(2339)
```

How can I get around this?

P.S: If I try to remove the first return type from the definition file, it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During runtime, the code does not know which object `getLinkPreview()` will be resolved to. Typescript will not allow the confusion happened.

To workaround on this, you need a type guard.

Few options for you:

1. Using poor's man way

```js
const linkPreview = await getLinkPreview(payload.link);

if ('images' in linkPreview) {
   console.log(linkPreview.images)
}
```

2. Using type assertion

```
const linkPreview = await getLinkPreview(payload.link);

if (<SecondObjectInterface>linkPreview.images) {
   console.log(linkPreview.images)
}

// OR
if ((linkPreview as SecondObjectInterface).images) {
   console.log(linkPreview.images)
}
```

More information on type guards is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the compile error message is very telling. It's complaining because that code is trying to perform [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the property `images` from an object that **can't be guaranteed to contain that property**.

The return type of `getLinkPreview` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), which means that it returns an object that will satisfy at least one of the members of the union type. So because it's possible for `getLinkPreview` to return an object that looks like:

```js
{
    url: string;
    mediaType: string;
    contentType: string;
    favicons: any[];
}
```

TypeScript is complaining that this object does not have the `images` property.

### So how to handle this?

As a general solution, you can store the result of `getLinkPreview` in a variable, then do a null-check for the `images` property. If it does have the unique property, then you can cast it into the appropriate type (you may want to do additional testing).

Comment: its always better to have the solution provided in form of code.